# DocumentDb Emulator not working - Service Unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm experiencing some problems while using the DocumentDB Emulator (v. **1.11.136.2**).
I'm able to see the Explorer (https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html) but I cannot create any Database\Collection using either the Explorer and the SDK (I tried with the sample code provided by that page and my own code).

I always get:

```
    {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"code\":\"ServiceUnavailable\",\"message\":\"Service is currently unavailable.\\r\\nActivityId: 9c9f56f8-91f9-4fad-b592-0c6bd5bbd300\"}","responseJSON":{"code":"ServiceUnavailable","message":"Service is currently unavailable.\r\nActivityId: 9c9f56f8-91f9-4fad-b592-0c6bd5bbd300"},
"status":503,
"statusText":"error"}
```

I'm running Windows 10. I already tried to restart the PC and reinstall the SDK\Emulator.

Comment: Please try to shut down emulator and then deleting DocumentDB emulator data directory (`c:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\DocumentDBEmulator`) and see if this solves the problem for you. We have had similar issue and following these instructions solved our problem.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: Can you update your question with the DocumentDB emulator version?

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to include the code you're using to connect to, and work with, the emulator. Also: Did this work at one point and stop working, or is it that it never worked in the first place?

Comment: The code is not so important, because I get the error even if I try to create a new database\collection directly in the web interface. Unfortunately it never worked on my machine.

Comment: Do you have a try to follow  the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator) to develop with DocumentDB emulator?  DocumentDB Emulator (v. 1.11.136.2) works correctly on my side follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-nosql-local-emulator). And I also find a simlar [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/185), you also can give your feedback.

Comment: Yes I read that document and the issue too.. I wrote to askdocdb@microsoft.com some days ago, let's if they reply me. I'll keep you updated

Comment: @MartinoBordin - any update from Microsoft, hitting the same issue.

Comment: @Ovi I had a VPN Client that was interfering with emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Support answer:

> The failure is when the emulator tries to bring up the network stack. 
>   We have seen this on some customer machines where 3rd network filter
>   drivers break some of the Windows networking APIs that we use. 
>   Examples of these include drivers installed by Pulse Secure (or
>   Juniper network).   I think we’ve also seen this type of failure with
>   some 3rd party antivirus products.
>
> Typically uninstalling the 3rd party software should resolve the
>   issue.

Comment: Which 3rd party network filter drivers are they? I have no idea where to start looking...

Comment: A VPN client for instance

Answer (score 3):

To fix this I had to perform a "Reset Data" on the Emulator.
This is probably due to some issue around updating from DocumentDb to Cosmo Db emulator.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to change ConnectionMode to **Gateway** as

[image]

to

[image]

and it worked perfectly